# Single-page application and web-page title

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, single-page-application

Should a single page web app should have different titles for different routes?

Let say we have single-page app which have below routes:

- `/#dashboard`
- `/#users`
- `/#items`

When route `/#dashboard` loads, should the page title reflect the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the page title should reflect the current route. I've used HistoryJS for managing both the URL and the page title. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ You can send the page name along with the URL you want. It uses HTML5 PushState but also has support for older browsers.